# Images received though social media end up in the camera-app Gallery

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, camera, gallery

Lately, in the Gallery app associated with the camera app of my Samsung phone (Android 8.0.0), I can see not only past pictures I've taken with the phone camera, but also pictures that people are sending me through whatsapp, viber and other messenger/social media apps.

I didn't see any options in the Gallery app itself to have those land not in the same place as my camera-taken pictures.

Is there any way to keep the two categories of pictures (whatsapp attachments; and camera pictures) separated?

Comment: Which gallery that is (exact package name)? Why don't you try some other gallery app? There are many free, open-source, feature-rich galleries available.

Comment: It's the stock Gallery that one gets taken to when one taps on the circular icon denoting the last-taken picture, in the camera app. I'd prefer to keep using this Gallery app due to its ease of access (double-press home button to fire up the camera app)